# Magento merge javascript omit files

Tags: magento

I've found that prototype.js messes up some things whenever I merge javascript on my store.  Is there a way to have Magento omit prototype.js when it merges javascript files?  I assume I could rewrite whatever function does this,  but I'm not sure how to find where this happens.  Is there a good way to find what is happening and where in Magento?

Answer (score 3):

You can omit a file from being combined by adding a param. For example, in your page.xml you could change the following line:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

to:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>prototype</params></action>
```

All files with the same param are combined together.

Answer (score 2):

The magento merging system does n't work well in a lot of cases. I think for better understanding u should check [Here](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/why-you-shouldnt-merge-javascript/)

There is not an option to exclude a file from admin panel but i guess u can separate them by using grouping technology mentioned in the above blog.

Instead of using the default merging system i suggest u sld try [FooMan Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html)

Answer (score 0):

install `mod_pagespeed` by google on server zero configuration for your magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load prototype.js link in head.phtml file. This way don't merge your file, and you don't need to add it via xml.

It is not the best practice anyway, but it works perfectly.